# Xattribute having row number as attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

With the help of list `seriesDetails`, using LINQ Im generating the sample XML,

```
 var result=
              from sc in seriesDetails    
              select new XElement("A",
              new XAttribute("id", sc.A),
              new XElement("B",sc.B),
              new XAttribute("id", sc.B));
```

Sample XML generating as mentioned below,

```
<A id="asdf">
    <B id="qwer" />
</A>
<A id="sdfg">
    <B id="bmnm" />
</A >
```

I Need to add another attribute called `sequence` for `<A>` tag which should be the row number from the list `seriesDetails`.

Expected output :

```
<A id="asdf" sequence="1">
    <B id="qwer" />
</A>
<A id="sdfg" sequence="2">
    <B id="bmnm" />
</A >
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which provides row number (i.e. element's index):

```
  from x in seriesDetails.Select((sc, i) => new { sc, sequence = i + 1 })   
  select new XElement("A",
           new XAttribute("id", x.sc.A),
           new XAttribute("sequence", x.sequence),
           new XElement("B", // do not provide inner text to element B
              new XAttribute("id", x.sc.B)));
```

Another option is introducing new variable outside your query which will keep row number

```
int sequence = 0;
var result=
      from sc in seriesDetails 
      select new XElement("A",
               new XAttribute("id", sc.A),
               new XAttribute("sequence", ++sequence),
               new XElement("B", 
                  new XAttribute("id", sc.B)));
```

Comment: Sergey Berezovskiy - Thanks! Another question on how to to add sequence number for sub element `<B>` as well?

Comment: @user2729272 you want to put same sequence number for attribute B?

Comment: yes, sequence number for each `<B>` under `<A>`. Something like, `<A id="asdf">
    <B id="qwer" SNO= "1" />
 <B id="qwer" SNO= "2"/>
</A>
<A id="sdfg">
    <B id="bmnm" SNO= "1" />
 <B id="bmnm" SNO= "2" />
</A >`

Comment: @user2729272 you can use same approach as first option shows - use `Select((b,i) => new {b, sequence = i + 1}` when selecting B items